# Facebook - Page Activity and Messenger Notifications

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-messenger

How do I get notifications via Messenger of activity on Pages I manage?

I think I used to get them but I don't seem to be anymore.

If someone posts, likes a picture, messages, etc... I should get a Messenger noticed.

Comment: Would downvoter care to comment on the downvote? Hard to correct a questions without help.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook notifies user on Facebook(for pages activity and groups)

You can't receive notifications on messenger regarding pages and groups.

**You can see in messenger the number of new notifications on Facebook.
That's all.**